# Unicode escape not working with user input

Tags: python, unicode-escapes

I have a short python script that's supposed to print the unicode character from a number the user inputs. However, it's giving me an error.

Here's my code:

```
print("\u" + int(input("Please enter the number of a unicode character: ")))
```

It's giving me this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in 
position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: You can't create an escape sequence from two parts. It is effectively one character.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent to a unicode escape that can be multiple characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to `unicode_escape` the string itself:

```
input_int = int(input("Please enter the number of a unicode character: "))
# note that the `r` here prevents the `SyntaxError` you're seeing here
# `r` is for "raw string" in that it doesn't interpret escape sequences
# but allows literal backslashes
escaped_str = r"\u{}".format(input_int)  # or `rf'\u{input_int}'` py36+
import codecs
print(codecs.decode(escaped_str, 'unicode-escape'))
```

A sample session:

```
>>> input_int = int(input("Please enter the number of a unicode character: "))
Please enter the number of a unicode character: 2603
>>> escaped_str = r"\u{}".format(input_int)  # or `rf'\u{input_int}'` py36+
>>> import codecs
>>> print(codecs.decode(escaped_str, 'unicode-escape'))
☃
```

Comment: that only works with 4+ digit unicode characters for some reason.

Comment: the `\u` escape sequence is only for 4+, `\x` is for the shorter ones.  Plus you're losing hex characters too so your `int(...)` idea is less than ideal.  For instance `'\u260b'` -- you'll probably need to rethink the approach slightly (like not using `int`, and using `\x` when it is of length 2)